# MySQL error 1054 unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have some tables and i tried to execute the following query

```
select placename , staff.name , subjectname from places , staff , subject 
where places_place_id = place_id and staff.staff_id = times.staff_staff_id 
and subject.subject_id=times.subject_subject_id and times.time_from=8 and times.time_to=9
```

it keep giving that error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'times.places_place_id' in 'where clause'

Although the column already exists and i tried also to use backticks and single quotes and nothing works [image]

Comment: May I ask what do you think 'times' is in your request (there'd no times in your FROM)??

Comment: (1) You don't have `times` in the `FROM` clause.  (2) More importantly.  You are using an archaic syntax that has been out-of-date for *decades*.  Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: And please don't "unformat" the question

Comment: it's my fault
it worked thanks

Comment: **Gordon Linoff** thanks my friend , i appreciate your Advice

Comment: **RC** i apologize , i'm new in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand the execution of select query when you use objects of tables.
Here,object.columnname refers to a particular column in the object table.
Add times table in your query in FROM clause.

Therefore,your query should be

`select placename , staff.name , subjectname from places , staff , subject,times where places_place_id = place_id and staff.staff_id = times.staff_staff_id and subject.subject_id=times.subject_subject_id and times.time_from=8 and times.time_to=9;`

You have also missed a semi-colon.